# Задача на асинхронность в js

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout

Все привет! Несколько дней промучился с решение задачи по промисам, но к элегантному решению не пришел... Использовать setTimeout с различными таймингами є кажется тупо, но и вариант с Promise не могу что-то адекватное придумать. Помогите решить задачу и объяснить мене ее. Буду благодарен за любую помощь))
Используя известные средства асинхронного выполнения (setTimeout и Promise) и не изменяя вертикальный порядок вызова функций 2, 1, 4, 3 в исходном коде, внесите изменения в код таким образом, чтобы после полного завершения выполнения программы в массиве completionFlags содержалась последовательность ['1' , '2', '3', '4'].

Стартовый код:

```
const completionFlags = [];

async function asyncActions() {
   // ========== Начало зоны редактирования ===============
   action('2');
   action('1');
   action('4');
   action('3');
   // ========== Конец зоны редактирования ===============
}

function action(pos) {
   completionFlags.push(pos);
}
```

Comment: _Использовать setTimeout с различными таймингами_ - что конкретно не нравится в этом решении?

Comment: Что можно делать в "зоне редактирования"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Используя известные средства асинхронного выполнения (setTimeout и Promise) и не изменяя вертикальный порядок вызова функций 2, 1, 4, 3 в исходном коде, внесите изменения в код таким образом, чтобы после полного завершения выполнения программы в массиве completionFlags содержалась последовательность ['1' , '2', '3', '4'].

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const completionFlags = [];

// Вызываем асинхронную функцию
asyncActions()
  .then(_ => console.log(completionFlags))
  .catch(console.log)

async function asyncActions() {
  // ========== Начало зоны редактирования ===============

  // запускаем все промисы и ждем их завершения
  return await Promise.all([
    action('2'),
    action('1'),
    action('4'),
    action('3'),
  ])
  // ========== Конец зоны редактирования ===============
}

function action(pos) {
  // возвращаем промис, который закончится через (pos * 10) милисекунд
  return new Promise(res => {
    // запускаем таймер, который по истечении своего времени запустит, переденную ему, функцию
    setTimeout(_ => {
      completionFlags.push(pos);
      // вызываем удачное завершение промиса
      res()
    }, pos * 10)
  })
}
```

Еще один вариант "только в зоне"...

```js
const completionFlags = [];

asyncActions()
  .then(_ => console.log(completionFlags))
  .catch(console.log)

async function asyncActions() {
  // ========== Начало зоны редактирования ===============

  // запускаем все промисы и ждем их завершения
  return await Promise.all([
    // делаем промисы, которые завершатся в нужной нам последовательности
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => (action('2'), res()), 2 * 10)),
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => (action('1'), res()), 1 * 10)),
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => (action('4'), res()), 4 * 10)),
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => (action('3'), res()), 3 * 10)),
  ])
  // ========== Конец зоны редактирования ===============
}

function action(pos) {
  completionFlags.push(pos);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ и решение))  Может бить глупо, но можете 
объяснить это решение.. Для меня это сложно

Comment: выглядит будто редактировать можно только внутри зоны редактирования. А `function action` находится _вне_ этой зоны

Comment: @Grundy, я спрашивал про "зону"... :) Ответа не получил.

Comment: @SerhiyGerych, там всего три действия... `new Promise()`, `setTimeout()` и `Promise.all()` - что именно там "объяснять"?

Comment: @ksa, _там всего три действия_ - вот их и объяснить

Comment: @Grundy, пописал комментарии...

Comment: @Grundy, При создании промисе в аргументе передаёте res, но потом делаете вызов res(). Что там находиться в res? и метод написание _ взамен () странный)))

Comment: @ksa, Зона где можно редактировать код и вносить изменение, но прошлом вариант Grundy мене больше понравился, но под задачу не подходит

Comment: @SerhiyGerych, для данного случая в `res()` ничего передавать не нужно, тут важен сам вызов этой функции. Это положительное завершение промиса. `_ =>` считай стандартное описание стрелочной функции. Можешь написать и так `() =>`, коли есть желание...

Comment: @ksa _считай стандартное описание стрелочной функции_ - не считай. Раз уж человек не знает где можно скобки опускать и почему а где нельзя - то лучше рассказать, а не говорить просто запомни

Comment: Хорошо... У стрелочной функции, при одном параметре, можно не указывать круглые скобки - `a =>`. Поскольку символ подчеркивания так же допустим в именах переменных - мы можем его смело использовать, кагбэ намекая, что сам-то параметр нам и не нужен. Отсюда и такое использование - `_ =>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const completionFlags = [];

async function asyncActions() {
   // ========== Начало зоны редактирования ===============
   Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
      action('2'); // добавляем в очередь микрозадач
   })
   action('1');
   setTimeout(()=>{
    action('4'); // добавляем в очередь макрозадач
   }, 0)
   Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
      action('3'); // добавляем в очередь микрозадач
   })
   // ========== Конец зоны редактирования ===============
}

function action(pos) {
   completionFlags.push(pos);
}

asyncActions()

setTimeout(()=>{
 console.log(completionFlags) // добавляем в очередь макрозадач чтобы в конце посмотреть после всех очередей массив
}, 0)
```